# Getting the file details from _api/web/lists

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the following url to get a file based on the ID in the list:

```
https://<site>/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('<library>')/items(itemId)/
```

I am getting data back, but I need the properties of this item that are returned from a search, especially the ServerRedirectEmbedURL, ServerRedirectPreviewURL, and the ServerDirectedURL as well as the Path so I can download this file.  The library and itemId are coming from a local database and I am stuffing them into the url and doing a get.  I get a response and can see the JSON returned, but I am not seeing the fields I would need in a search.  I am using the right call here or do I need another call to get this data?  This is all so mysterious so I do appreciate all the help I am getting.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for a while, but eventually found that you need to add `?$expand=file`to the query string URL, e.g `https://<site>/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('<library>')/items(itemId)/?$expand=file`

This will then include a File object in the JSON response containing the goodies you are after.

Comment: I added this to the end of the line and sent it to the server.  I got a response but I didn't see anywhere in the response where the ServerRedirectEmbedURL, ServerRedirectPreviewURL, ServerDirectedURL, and Path were located in the JSON response.  I get some additional fields, but not these  fields.  I'll keep digging and if I find something post it here.